# Singular point problem

Tags: plotting, singularity

I have two functions:

```
Uinf = 1;
Λ = 30;

ϕ[x_, y_] := Λ*Log[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/(2*Pi) + Uinf*x;
ψ[x_, y_] := Λ*ArcTan[y/x]/(2*Pi) + Uinf*y;
```

I want to plot these two functions with a ContourPlot and the result should be some like this:

[image]

But my result is like this:

[image]

I have a singular point at x=0. So, how can avoid this and get the optimal result like the first image?

The line code that I'm using for plot is this:

```
Show[ContourPlot[ϕ[x, y], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, 
ContourShading -> None, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness -> 0.003], 
Contours -> 10],
ContourPlot[ψ[x, y], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, 
ContourShading -> None, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness -> 0.003], 
Contours -> 15], 
ContourPlot[ψ[x, y] == Λ/2, {x, -50, 
50}, {y, -50, 50}, ContourShading -> None, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness -> 0.006], 
Contours -> 15]]
```

Comment: Use `ArcTan[x, y]` instead of `ArcTan[y/x]`.

Comment: Oh great @J.M. . Problem solved! Thanks!!